# Verify Menu Buttons in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am working on script where navigating to Menu and clicking on menu button and it will navigate to specific page, again verifying if page title is as expected, then clicking on second menu button and repeating same process for all menu buttons.

Here is html code

```
<md-menu-content width="6" role="menu">
<md-menu-item>
<button class="md-button md-ink-ripple" ng-transclude="" type="button" ng-click="gotoPost()" role="menuitem" aria-label="Create A Post">
<span class="ng-scope">Creae A Post</span>
<div class="md-ripple-container" style=""/>
</button>
</md-menu-item>
<md-menu-divider role="separator"/>
<md-menu-item>
<button class="md-button md-ink-ripple" ng-transclude="" type="button" ng-click="goToProfile()" role="menuitem" aria-label="PROFILE">
<span class="ng-scope">PROFILE</span>
<div class="md-ripple-container" style=""/>
</button>
</md-menu-item>
<md-menu-divider role="separator"/>
  // And so on ..............
```

Here is my selenium code:

**VERIFY PROFILE LINK**

```
WebElement mnuElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/access/allow-intent/allow-intent/allow-intent/allow-intent/allow-intent/allow-intent/allow-navigation/allow-navigation/main-navigation/div/md-menu/img"));
// Move cursor to the Main Menu Element
    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
   builder.moveToElement(mnuElement, 764, 90).click(mnuElement);
   builder.perform();
    // Giving 5 Secs for submenu to be displayed
    Thread.sleep(5000L);
     WebElement submnuElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='menu_container_3']/md-menu-content/md-menu-item[1]/button"));
    // Clicking on the Hidden SubMenu
    //driver.findElement(By.Id("sbEle")).Click();
     submnuElement.click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
     //0OSP.SelectOption().click();
    //0driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(550, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    //0OSP.Clicklogadive().click();
    //0driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    Recreational RC = new Recreational(driver); 
    System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl()); 
    driver.navigate().refresh();

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    String post= RC.Getrtitle().getText();

    System.out.println(post)
    Assert.assertEquals(post, "Create Post");
    System.out.println("\n! You have landed to the page: " +post + "Page");
    driver.navigate().back();

    // ************* VERIFY PROFILE LINK ***********************
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    WebElement mnuElement1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/access/allow-intent/allow-intent/allow-intent/allow-intent/allow-intent/allow-intent/allow-navigation/allow-navigation/main-navigation/div/md-menu/img"));
    // Move cursor to the Main Menu Element
    Actions builder1 = new Actions(driver);
   builder1.moveToElement(mnuElement1, 764, 90).click(mnuElement1);
   builder1.perform();
   Thread.sleep(5000L); // Giving 10Secs for submenu to be displayed
   WebElement submnuElement1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='menu_container_3']/md-menu-content/md-menu-item[2]/button"));
    // Clicking on the Hidden SubMenu
   submnuElement1.click();
   driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   Profile PF = new Profile(driver); 
   System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl()); 
   driver.navigate().refresh();
   driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

   String profiletitle = PF.Getptitle().getText(); 
    Assert.assertEquals(profiletitle, "Profile");
    System.out.println("\n! You have landed to the page: " +profiletitle + "Page");
```

-- My script to clicking on create post menu button, going to that page, verifying page heading and going to back to home page. here I want to select second menu button but script stops at this point.

Please help.

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? Please read the help topics on how to ask a good question. You need to research your own issue, find code samples, etc. and write your own code to solve the issue. If you do all that and still can't figure it out, then come back and edit your question and add notes from the research you did, the code you have tried reduced to a [mcve], and what the result was... any error messages, etc. It's also very important to include any relevant HTML and properly format the HTML and code.

Comment: `@id='menu_container_3'` is not even on the html code. Also please fix the indentation if possible.